# A question on a bounded sequence in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $r>0$, and $2 \le q \le 2^*$. 
Suppose that $\{u_k\}_k$ is a bounded sequence in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and
$\lim_{k\to \infty} \sup_{y \in \mathbb{R}^n} \int_{B_r(y)}|u_k|^q dx \rightarrow 0.$
How can I show that $u_k \rightarrow 0$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $2 < p < 2^*$?

Comment: what does $2^*$ mean?

Comment: Probably $2^*=\frac{2n}{n-2}$ .

Comment: Can you conclude from the limit that $u_k\to 0$ in $L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)$ ?

Comment: Yes, I mean $2^*=\frac{2n}{n-2}$ as usual.

Comment: @user2013 As "usual"?